# ajax label on click text

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to display the content of a label in a text fieldwith onClick event how can I do it,
Is there any specific method to do it or is there any other way.

Please help I am new to ajax.

Thanks

Comment: you'r question is not explaining exactly what you wan't from code.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#JavaScript_core_skills

Comment: It doesn't like like this has anything to do with Ajax at all.

Comment: Do you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/5LfHJ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO need of ajax for this you can do this by using jquery instead simply

In html:

```
  <input type="text" name="txt1" value="" id="txt"/>
  <label for="checking" id="label">checking</label>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Click" id="butt" />
```

In Javascript:

```
  $("#butt").click(function(){
     var lab_val = $("#label").text();
     document.getElementByID("txt").value =lab_val;
     // or $("#txt").val(lab_val);
   });
```

Comment: This should be a comment - its not an answer

Comment: Why add a half finished answer 10 minutes before you add the proper answer ..... and there is no jQuery tag on this question

Comment: ya i know no need of going to ajax we can do it just using javascript or jquery

Comment: I want that every time a change occurs the data should be updated to the server